# Will Not Compare 2 strings that are equal that were read in from PrintWriter

Tags: java, hashtable, string-comparison

I am writing a program that takes a document created by one program by PrinterWriter and then hashes the lines in that document to an array in the new program.  The hash is done by using the ASCII code for the letter and adding them up.  I am able to get the correct hash for each line and save it in the hash table.  By the way, it is a list of countries that is hashed.  My problem is that it does not seem to be able to compare the countries entered by the user, even though it is copy and paste, to the ones in the hash table to display them.  It is not only supposed to display the country in the hash table, but all the ones leading up to the hash table.  So if one was supposed to go to spot 23 but went to spot 26, display 23-26 to show clustering.  I have tired everything to get it to work, but nothing seems to work, please help.  I have included some of the code:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Hashing
{
    String[] line = new String[238];
    String[] HashTable = new String[300];

    public Hash() {
        for (int i = 0; i< HashTable.length; i++) {
            HashTable[i]=null;
        }
    }

    public void readIn()throws Exception {
        Scanner ln = new Scanner(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),     "user.home.CountryUnSortedFormat.txt"));
        int i = 0;
        while (ln.hasNextLine()) {
            line[i] = ln.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
    }

    public int toASCII(String input) {
        int total = 0;
        char character;
        String str = input.replaceAll(",","").trim();
        if (str.length() > 50) {
            for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
                int ascii = str.charAt(i);
                if (ascii > 32) {
                    total = total + ascii;
                }
            }
        } else if (str.length()<50) {
            for (int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
                int ascii = str.charAt(i);
                if (ascii > 32) {
                    total = total + ascii;
                }
            }
        }
        return total % 300;
    }

    public void hashIt(String input, int where){
        int counter = where;  
        if (where==299 && HashTable[where]!=null){
            counter = 0;
        }
        while (HashTable[counter]!=null){
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("Country = " + input + " HashValue = " + where + " actual HashSpot = " + counter);
        HashTable[counter]=input;
    }

public boolean showCountries(String paramCountry, int where){
int location = where;
int length = paramCountry.length();
while (!(HashTable[location].substring(0,length).contains(paramCountry))){
System.out.println("Input = " + paramCountry + " and HashTableCOunty = " +     HashTable[location].substring(0,length));
System.out.println("The Hash Table Index is " + location + " " + HashTable[location]);
     if (!(HashTable[location].substring(0,length).contains(paramCountry))){
     location++;
     }
     else if (HashTable[location].substring(0,length).contains(paramCountry)){
     System.out.println("The Hash Table Index is " + location + " " + HashTable[location]);
     System.out.println("Eguals");
     return true;
     }
     if (location==300||HashTable[location]==null){
     System.out.println("End");
     return false;
     }
     }
 return false;
 } 


    public void displayHashTable() {
        for (int i = 0; i<HashTable.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("i = " + i + " " + HashTable[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        Hash H = new Hash();
        H.readIn();
        for (int i = 0; i< 238; i++) {
            int where = H.toASCII(H.line[i]);
            H.hashIt(H.line[i], where);
        }
        H.displayHashTable();

        String UserChoice;
        System.out.println("Enter the Name of the Country you wish to locate in the Hash Table or Enter -1 to quit: ");
        UserChoice = kb.nextLine();
        while (!(UserChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))) {
            int index = H.toASCII(UserChoice);
            boolean error = H.showCountries(UserChoice, index);
            while (error == false) {
                System.out.println("The country you searched for is not in the hash table.  Try again.");
                UserChoice = kb.nextLine();
                index = H.toASCII(UserChoice);
                error = H.showCountries(UserChoice, index);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter the Name of the Country you wish to locate in the Hash Table or Enter -1 to quit: ");
            UserChoice = kb.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it prints the hash table by using the ASCII code where it is supposed to be until it reaches null or end of the hash tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us look at `showCountries` method:

```
public boolean showCountries(String paramCountry, int where) {
    //....
    return false;
}
```

I removed every line, that does not contain a `return` statement. As you can see, you always return `false` no matter if the searched element was found or not.

Therefore this loop:

```
while (error == false) {
    //...
}
```

is like an infinite loop.

Change the code in your `showCountries` method to return `true`, it the country was found.

And consider changing the variable name `error` to something else. `error == false` sounds like "everything was ok", but this is not the case here.

If I understand your code correctly, you can change this:

```
else if (paramCountry.equals(HashTable[location].substring(0,length))) {
    System.out.println("The Hash Table Index is " + location + " " + HashTable[location]);
    break;
}
```

to:

```
else if (paramCountry.equals(HashTable[location].substring(0,length))) {
    System.out.println("The Hash Table Index is " + location + " " + HashTable[location]);
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**

Another error-prone point is right here:

```
int length = paramCountry.length()-1;

while (!(paramCountry.equals(HashTable[location].substring(0,length)))) {
//...
```

You're cutting off the last character due to the usage of `-1`.
A small example:

```
paramCountry = "Eng";
HashTable[0] = "England";
int length = paramCountry.length()-1; // 2 (paramCountry.length() is 3)
```

And this are the results with the above values:

```
HashTable[0].substring(0,length)) // "En"
paramCountry.equals(HashTable[0].substring(0, length)) // "Eng".equals("En") -> false
```

So, you can remove that `-1` or get rid of that `substring` and use [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead.

**Edit 2:**

So, after your edit use `contains` instead of `substring` you only have one error left (the last one I cuurently see ):

```
while (!(HashTable[location].substring(0, length).contains(paramCountry))) {
    // ...
}
return false;
```

Before you're calling the method `showCountries` you're calculating the possible position by calling `H.toASCII(UserChoice);`. This position is given to the method as `location` there it is used in the above `while` loop. This loop will be skipped, because the search country is already found. The bad thing is: you will return `false` in this case.

Now I suggest to change this return to `return true;` because this line will only be reached if the searched country was already found (and the while loop was skipped). If the country could not be found, you will return `false` in this if body: `if (location==300||HashTable[location]==null)`.

Comment: ok, but it still seems it is not able to compare the Strings and say they are equal.  I have tried a quite a few ways to make it compare, even though I know it is equal, it still says they are not.  How can I compare the strings?

Comment: My problem was, and maybe that is where I need to take more time to look at it, is that it never got into that if else because it won't say they are equal.  I just assumed the return false at the bottom was ok because as long as at some point the Strings equaled, it would return true.  But, like I said it never went into that if else statement, I put print lines in there to test at one point, that is why I know it never went in there.

Comment: Have you noticed, that you never call `makeHashTable`? But you're calling an unknown method `hashIt`. So can you fix your code? And check that you hashtable is filled correctly at the moment where the user enters his first search.

Comment: I do have a displayHashTable() method that displays the whole hash Table, I cut some things out cause it was so long.  The hash table is correct, everything hashes to the correct spot.  In fact when I searched, I copied and pasted from the printed out hash table.  I also just tried changing the return values.  It prints everything from the spot where it should have been to the next null spot or the end of the hash table, passing over the String it was looking for.  I think the problem is how I am comparing the Strings, even though it looks right.  That is the part that is driving me nuts!!!!

Comment: @user320087 Ok, now it is a little bit clearer :). Also please notice my edit.

Comment: I know it is a little mixed up. Thanks for being patient.  Do you have any suggestions on the fact that the Strings are not equal.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user320087 `Also please notice my edit.` you could do this ;). (I mean the edit of my answer and not the edit of your question)

Comment: The HashIt() method was to read in the array.  It does not compare the String inputed by the user to the Strings in the HashTable.

Comment: @user320087 And why do you think that my edit is talking about the `hashIt` method? This is your code, so you should be able to see where this code snippet comes from. Spoiler: the `showCountries` method.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I removed the -1 from the length, but it is still not working.  It never gets into that if else statement where the Strings are equal.  What is the contains method?

Comment: @user320087 Read the linked JavaDoc for more information. And start using a debugger to step through the program.

Comment: I looked up the contains(). Thanks, I did not realize I could do that.  It still is not returning true.  I changed my display countries in my program.  It still does not compare the Strings because is never gets into the if else.  Am I comparing them correctly?

Comment: @user320087 Yes you do, please read my second edit :). Also please not that `contains` find the search string on any position: `"England".contains("gla")` is true. This might be a problem if you tried to find `Bangladesh` instead. Also note that Strings are case sensitive by default.

Comment: The where or location is not always the correct location on the hash table, it is looking where it should have been hashed to, but there may have been collisions.  It displays all the collisions up to the searched country.  That was my thinking for the while loop.  To print out all the collisions up to the searched for country.

Comment: @user320087 If it is not the correct location, then the program will enter the while loop and return `true` or `false` from there. But if it is the correct location, then it will return `true`. Can you check that change please?

Comment: You have given me a lot of advice and taught me a few things.  I am gonna keep playing with it.  I am going to try and rewrite a few things and see if I can get it right.  Thank you so much for your help and time, Tom

Comment: @user320087 So, there are two things left: we can clean up the comments if you like and you can accept the answer if it helped solving your problem/question.